# How do I remove the <br> tags from wp_list_categories?

Tags: categories

If I pass in `'style' => 'none'` as an argument to `wp_list_categories`, the `<li>` tags  are removed. That's great, but `<br>` tags are injected. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 4):

### The new `separator` attribute of `wp_list_categories()`

I think you are looking for the new `separator` attribute, that will be [introduced here in WordPress 4.4](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1579e45d4199a7fe8f7bae0e49f81ba483bdf6ab/wp-includes/category-template.php#L539) that's just around the corner. I located the trac ticket here [#9025](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9025).

Then you can use:

```
$args = [
    'style'     => 'none',
    'separator' => '', // <-- Removes the default one
];

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

where by default it's `'seperator' => '<br />'`;

### Example:

We get:

```
<a href="http://example.tld/category/red/" >Red</a>
<a href="http://example.tld/category/green/" >Green</a>
<a href="http://example.tld/category/blue/" >Blue</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="http://example.tld/category/red/" >Red</a><br />
<a href="http://example.tld/category/green/" >Green</a><br />
<a href="http://example.tld/category/blue/" >Blue</a><br />
```

Comment: You are quite busy with 4.4. Just been to busy with other stuff to really peak into 4.4, seems I need to get my priorities straight here, falling behind, ;-)

Comment: Lots of interesting stuff and improvements in 4.4 ;-)  I just filed a ticket [#34751](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34751) to improve the cluttered default arguments in `wp_list_categories()` for better readability.  @PieterGoosen

Comment: That would be a great. Some code in core are really bad when it comes to readability. Hope your ticket makes core. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'echo' => 0,
    // your other parameters
);
echo str_replace( "<br>", "", wp_list_categories( $args ) );
```

Comment: hmmm, I have no idea why people downvoted this.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly i can not comment yet but James Jones is right in wp-includes/category-template.php @1103 you'll see that if the style parameter is not set it will produce a `<br />` at the end of each element.

the only thing that is not right is that it should be

```
str_replace( "<br />", "", wp_list_categories( $args ) );
```

alsoe keep in mind to set the parameter `echo` to false otherwise it will output the html right away.